# SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:79
      let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
      ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

im trying to run the command:

```
npm install async-foreach
```

but my server is giving me this error, i have no idea whats going on, my system is up to date it has

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Comment: What does running `node --version` in your terminal output? `let` was introduced in node v4

Comment: solved the issue by deleting and installing node